# How to use Microsoft Fakes (shims) to create fakes/mocks for await/async methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, microsoft-fakes

When you create a new MVC 5 project you get an account controller (AccountController) which contains Login method. My question is: how will you create a unit test to test this method using Microsoft Fakes (Shim)?

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

So I have created this test method however I am unable to step into the login method and the execution stops after the first call. Here is my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            var shimUserManager = new ShimUserManager<ApplicationUser>();
            shimUserManager.FindAsyncStringString = (x, y) => { return new Task<ApplicationUser>(null); };

            var ctrl = new AccountController(shimUserManager);
            var result = ctrl.Login(new Models.LoginViewModel { UserName = "user", Password = "pass" }, "");
        }
    }
```

I have created a fake/shim for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core assembly

Comment: Reading your question I don't understand what do you want to fake - the view model?

Comment: Usually when using a shim, you don't create an instance but rather use the static `AllInstances` property to override all instances generated at runtime. To use it like you do here, you'd use a stub instead normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface IUserManager and inject it's implementation to your controller using MVC's Dependency Injection mechanism. The implementation will simply call the UserManager.FindAsync method. Then you will be able to mock this call in a unit test.

Example

```
public interface IUserManager
{
    User Find(string username, string password);
}

public class UserManagerImpl : IUserManager
{
    public User Find(string username, string password)
    {
        return await UserManager.FindAsync(username, password);
    }
}

public class AccountController
{
    private IUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    //user _userManager on your Login method.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. AccountManager is a class which exists in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity namespace. This is its signature:


public class UserManager<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : global::Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser


The idea is with using Microsoft Fakes I shouldn't need to inject anything in this scenario

Comment: Ah, ok I see. This is what I would do without using MS Fakes though.

Comment: Totally agree. This is how I do it as well using Moq however I kinda like the idea of using Microsoft Fakes when sometimes you find your self injecting stuff just for the sake of unit testing